# In istio telemetry, what's the difference between 'destination' and 'source' on reporter label?

Tags: kubernetes, istio, telemetry

It's written in the docs: 'Reporter: This identifies the reporter of the request. It is set to destination if report is from a server Istio proxy and source if report is from a client Istio proxy or a gateway.'

But isn't clear for me.

I use the metric istio_requests_total to know the request rate.

```
sum(irate(istio_requests_total{app_kubernetes_io_name="$app", namespace="default",reporter="destination"}[$__rate_interval])) by (namespace,app_kubernetes_io_name,response_code)
```

This works fine but I wan't to ignore the health check requests on my pod so I'm thinking if makes sense to change from 'destination' to 'source' on my query.

Answer (score 0):

`source` and `destination` refer to what side of the wire your stat is comming from. So, if you set it as `source`, it will report the requests made (outbound) by that selected workload, while if you choose `destination` it will report the received (inbound) requests on that selected workload.

I think it wouldn't make sense to change the `destination` for `source` here, because you wouldn't be measuring the actual traffic to the workload.

Besides, the kubelet health checks bypass the istio sidecar and work directly on each pod's container.

If, e.g., your health check is being done by a peer workload, you can use Istio's dimensions like the one below to prevent those incomming requests from being counted.

```
source_app="productpage"
source_canonical_revision="v1"
source_canonical_service="productpage"
```

Comment: This is more clear for me now. Each container has its own healthcheck. I think its not bad having your healthchecks considered on your dashboard.

Comment: Sure. I've used before "Restarts" metric, which is a proxy for pod's health status.